# How to use jquery to add horizontal image scroll in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I'm working on a webpage design in which I require an image scroll control to select an image. I'm trying to add horizontal scroll for images. I looked up on the internet to find free horizontal scroll controls and found one for free on [Horizontal image scroll sly](http://codepen.io/ritz078/pen/bEYOov).

Now the problem is I've not had much experience with jquery before, my project is on visual studio 2015 and i'm using chrome browser, I have a master page and it's child page where I need this scroll. so far it's not  working.

Here's what I did in masterpage:

```
<head runat="server"
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

And then in the child page I added all the given code from the reference site but i'm not getting the desired output.

Here's my output:
[image: output]

Any help on how to properly use this jquery would be appreciated.